# Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening

Tags: php

I have seen this question asked but I haven't been able to find my answer.

I made a small change on one page of my site. (changed the link of an icon that was in the header) Now just this one page is in ruins. There seems to be several files included to this page.

```
     db_conn_open.php
     languagefile.php
     includes.php
     70and100mphclub.php
     metainfo.php
     prototype.php
     getminicart.php
     style.css
     EM_popoutmenu_blue.css
     AC_RunActive_Content.js
```

Atleast these all open in DreamWeaver with the Source code when I open my 70and100mph.php, which is the one I wanted to do something with in the first place.

Now I have a warning on my page that looks like this:

```
Warning: include_once(MaxAmpsDigital/public_html/vsadmin/inc/languagefile.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/maxamps/public_html/70and100mphclub.php on line 7
```

It has one for every php file connected. My source code and the `70and100mph.php` both have this at the beginning:

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('none');
session_start();
ini_set('url_rewriter.tags', '');
include_once "MaxAmpsDigital/public_html/vsadmin/db_conn_open.php";
include_once "MaxAmpsDigital/public_html/vsadmin/inc/languagefile.php";
include_once "MaxAmpsDigital/public_html/vsadmin/includes.php";
include_once "MaxAmpsDigital/public_html/70and100mphclub.php";
include_once "MaxAmpsDigital/public_html/vsadmin/inc/metainfo.php";?>
```

I am thinking I need to find where the script is pulling these links to fix this? But I don't know where to begin... Or if that is even correct. 
Sorry for they length, I just wanted to be a specific as possible.
PLEASE HELP!
Camryn

Comment: As with every other question with this problem: *you have the wrong path to your files*. Almost certainly because you're using relative paths and not absolute paths.

Comment: Check permissions on the directories and files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is inside the same root, just use the relative path:

```
include_once('db_conn_open.php');
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

```
include_once  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/vsadmin/db_conn_open.php";
```

use `var_dump($_SERVER);` to get the appropriate value and build the full file path and applied to it.